# Setting up VS 2022 for MySql

Tags: visual-studio, mysql-connector

I am just starting to write VS2022 WebForms app and need a MySql connection.
I already have MySql Connector/Net 8.0.23 installed.
Database is MySql 8.0.23.  All applications ar vb.net.
I have read where I need to install "MySql for Visual Studio" to establish a server-connection in "Server Explorer".
But I am concerned that it will wipe out my 8.0.23 Connector with a later version.

1. Will this be a problem?
2. Is there any way I can just specify a connection using my existing 8.0.23 connector.
3. I have many/many applications already written for 8.0.23 so I can't upgrade all of those.

Thanks

I have tried setting up a new server in "Server Explorer" but it also wants a mysql connector that I don't have in the installed connectors for VS2022.

Comment: You do not NEED to setup your server in the server explorer, this is just an interface to see the server and it's content, something you could well do, and even potentially better outside of VS with dedicated MySQL tooling. The connector was needed for your apps, the server explorer, not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download "MySql Connector" from Devart. The problem is that it is no longer free: after a 30 days trial period, we have to buy a licence.

I am working with VS 2022 but I am considering installing VS 2019 because of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if you create a project in VS 2019 with a MySQL connection, then close it, and reopen it in VS 2022, the MySQL connection continues to work.

You can then close it in VS 2022, reopen it in VS 2019, make the changes to the DB (including Entity Framework), save it, then go back to VS 2022. Everything works.

This includes the Data Model *.edmx file, which can be viewed in VS 2022 but cannot be updated, unless you reopen the project in VS 2019.

I am using VS 2022 GitHub CoPilot AI and so far, this works flawlessly. MVC project with ~65,000 lines of code and a large DB.